# Mapping a domain/subdomain to a folder with .htaccess and hosts file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I am trying to do might not be possible.

I have a LAMP development server (running ubuntu 14.10). I access it via an IP address.

I have two folders on this server, 'admin' and 'frontend'. The web pages in those folders have various links using absolute paths (e.g. /css/style.css), and when you view 0.0.0.0/frontend, the absolute path is wrong and you don't get the CSS file. I want to somehow map admin.domain.dev (or similar URL) to 0.0.0.0/admin, and the same for frontend. I have mapped those domains to the IP of my server in my hosts file.

I thought I might be able to detect which subdomain was being used by .htaccess and map it to the appropriate folder. I have not been able to get this to work, but it could be that this is impossible, or my `mod_rewrite` is wrong.

I've tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin.domain.dev$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^admin.domain.dev$ /admin [L]
```

and a few similar variations with no luck.

Comment: `RewriteRule` only matches on the path component of the URL, not the host name.

Comment: And anyway – why would you want to do this via rewriting, instead of just configuring two virtual hosts for those domains?

Comment: There is no actual domain for the server, so I'm not sure as to how I would set this up.

Comment: `admin.domain.dev` and `frontend.domain.dev` _are_ your domains/host names here …

Comment: @CBroe thanks, I didn't think I could set up vhosts in a separate box like that. I got it working just how I wanted.